# Angular - Only show a div if something is present

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to make a div appear if there are no comments on an article but not sure how to use the ng-if correctly here.

In scope i have "comments" that is an empty array if there are no comments on an article but im not sure how exactly to check

Im using an ng-repeat to list the comments so id like to hide the div if there are no results in the ng-repeat.

This is the code from the default articles to hide a div if there are no articles overall but it doesnt narrow it down to individual items like comments.

```
   ng-if="articles.$resolved && !articles.length"
```

How can i change it to look for comments on the article?

The comments are NOT embedded in the article model. They are a separate model with the Article id as a value in the comments model.

Comment: create a container for your ng-repeat comments. put ng-if="$scope.comments.length > 0"

Comment: Make sure you're using the api for your version of angular. Some versions use ng-show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to hide a div if there are no articles and no comments. If that is the case, try this:

```
<div ng-if="articles.length> 0 && comments.length>0">
    <!-- Your content -->
</div>
```